# parsing values in pipeline from an array like variable

Tags: azure-devops

The following is excerpt from my pipeline YAML:

```
 strategy: 
    maxParallel: 4
    matrix:
      dev_1:
        instanceName: DEV1
      dev_2:
        instanceName: DEV2
      dev_3:
        instanceName: DEV3
      dev_4:
        instanceName: DEV4
```

What I would like to do is to declare a variable such as DEV1,DEV2,DEV3,DEV4 and then somehow parse these out in the matrix excerpt as follows:

```
 strategy: 
    maxParallel: 4
    matrix:
      dev_1:
        instanceName: $(instance[0])
      dev_2:
        instanceName: $(instance[1])
      dev_3:
        instanceName: $(instance[2])
      dev_4:
        instanceName: $(instance[4])
```

is there any way of doing something similar to this can be achieved ?